# Return all orders from a list of countries in Commerce v3

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, query, order, plugin-craftcommerce3

A little stuck on trying to get the query right for this, I have a module where I need to write a function that returns all orders placed with billing addresses in a selected list of countries. The `countryIso` field on the billingaddress is perfect, but Im not sure how to target it in an orders query.

For context, this is a VAT reporting tool and needs to be based on billing country, not order adjustments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Order element query joins the billing address, and you can access the table with `billing_address` so something like this should work.

`Order::find()->andWhere(['billing_address.countryId' => 1])->all();`

The country IDs are stored in `commerce_countries` in commerce 3.

This will also work in Commerce 4, but since the countries table is gone, you can get it by the country code:

`Order::find()->andWhere(['billing_address.countryCode' => 'AU'])->all();`

Comment: Would it be correct to have an array of countries in that query? 
`Order::find()->andWhere(['billing_address.countryId' => [1, 2, 3] ])->all();` ?

Comment: Got it...`$orders = Order::find()->andWhere(['in', 'billing_address.countryId', $countries])->all();`

Answer (score 1):

Based on Luke's Reply, here's the end result based on ISO values

```
 public static function getVatOrders()
    {
        $countryIds = [];
        $countriesISO = [
            'AT','BE','BG','ES','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GB','GR','HU','IE','IT','LV','LT','LU','MT','NL','PL','PT','RO','SE','SK','SI'
        ];

        foreach($countriesISO as $iso){
            $country = Commerce::getInstance()->getCountries()->getCountryByIso($iso);
            $id = $country->id;
            $countryIds[] = $id;
        }

        $orders = Order::find()->andWhere([
            'in',
            'billing_address.countryId',
            $countryIds
        ]);

        return $orders;
    }

}
```